# How to make Vuetify available in Nuxt's context

Tags: javascript, plugins, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm importing Vuetify.js in a Nuxt plugin and I would like to make it accesible to other plugins.
I tried to assign it directly to the context like the [vuetify-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/blob/38e628b89cb7f3002fc0c09f45120cb57541a20f/templates/plugin.js#L47).

`vuetify.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import options from '@/vuetify.options.js'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {...options})

export default ctx => {
  const vuetify = new Vuetify(options)

  ctx.app.vuetify = vuetify
  ctx.$vuetify = vuetify.framework

}
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/vuetify'
  ],
  ...
}
```

But I always get an `undefined` value...

`plugin.js`

```
export default function (ctx, inject) {
  console.log('app.vuetify :', ctx.app.vuetify) // undefined
  console.log('$vuetify :', ctx.$vuetify) // undefined
}
```

I also tried using the `inject` method like in this [post](https://graficos.net/blog/2019-11-03-how-to-make-vuetify-available-in-nuxts-context), but then I get a `Type Error : Cannot set property $vuetify of #<Vue> which has only a getter`.

`vuetify.js`

```
export default function(_, inject) {
  const vuetify = new Vuetify(options)
  inject('vuetify', vuetify)
}
```

NB: I register the plugin in a module using the `addPlugin` method.

`module.js`

```
module.exports = function (moduleOptions) {
  this.addPlugin({
    fileName: 'myplugin.js',
    moduleOptions,
    src: resolve(__dirname, 'plugin.js'),
    mode: 'client'
  })
}
```

Comment: Why you are not using https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module ?

Comment: @MajidZarrin This module isn't [maintained since a while](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/issues/389) and I need the latest vuetify release.

Comment: without context u can get vuetify with `this.$vuetify`

Comment: @Jazuly I need nuxt's context because I want to access vuetify in other plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that was a load order issue, because I had the same problem with the `axios` module. I had to change the Nuxt plugin load order using the [`extendPlugins` property](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-extend-plugins/).

`nuxt.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  extendPlugins(plugins) {
    const loadOrder = [
      'axios',
      'i18n',
      'vuetify',
      'myplugin'
    ]

    // Find indexes of a plugin/module by name
    const findAllIndex = (arr, pluginName) =>
            arr.reduce((acc, plugin, idx) => (
                    typeof plugin === 'object' && plugin.src.includes(pluginName)
                    || typeof plugin === 'string' && plugin.includes(pluginName)
                            ? [...acc, idx] : acc), [])

    // Update plugin load order
    const orderPlugins = (oldOrder, newOrder) => {
      const indexes = newOrder.flatMap(plugin => findAllIndex(oldOrder, plugin))
      const defaultOrder = oldOrder.filter((plugin, idx) => !indexes.includes(idx)) // filterNot
      const customOrder = indexes.map(idx => oldOrder[idx]) // select
      return [
        ...defaultOrder,
        ...customOrder
      ]
    }

    return orderPlugins(plugins, loadOrder)
  }
}
```

This is half a solution to me. I would like to find a way to delay the plugin injection directly from it until all required dependencies are loaded. If someone found out how to achieve that, feel free to answer this question and I'll accept it.